# Replace a column with text string and date string into 2 diferent columns power query

Tags: excel, powerquery

Logic 1
I have a column with different type of values on it, Text strings and date strings in the same column, I need to split it into 2 columns, one with the text string values and the other one with the date string values.

Logic 2
Or just replace the text values or the date format values, the problem is that the entire columne is a "TEXT TYPE COLUM", and I just need to replace the date format values. Example the values stored as xx/xx/xxxx

Here is the column.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO. This is not a free code-writing service, but we can help you if you show us more.  Please **edit your question** to show what you have tried;  what you expect your results to look like; and where you have run into problems.

Comment: Thanks for the correction you made @RonRosenfeld, it was a lot of help. Lucky for me the problem was solved with the answer bellow. I will improbe my logic and lenguage, next time I write another problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duplicate the column. Convert that column to date type. Replace the errors with nulls. Add a custom column with formula =if [col2] =null then [col1] else null

sample

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Duplicated Column" = Table.DuplicateColumn(Source, "Column3.1-Copia", "Column3.1-Copia - Copy"),
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Duplicated Column",{{"Column3.1-Copia - Copy", type date}}),
#"Replaced Errors" = Table.ReplaceErrorValues(#"Changed Type", {{"Column3.1-Copia - Copy", null}}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Replaced Errors", "Custom", each if [#"Column3.1-Copia - Copy"]=null then [#"Column3.1-Copia"] else null)
in  #"Added Custom"
```